# Where can one buy a SIM card at Woodlands checkpoint in Singapore?

Tags: borders, cellphones, singapore, malaysia

I'm entering Singapore via the [Woodlands checkpoint](https://maps.app.goo.gl/Za2SyRGL4besX7jN9) from Johor Bahru and I'd like to buy a SIM card to use in Singapore. Where can I buy a SIM card at the Woodlands checkpoint? Is the closest 7-Eleven to the checkpoint the closest place where one can buy a SIM card? (see screenshot below for the location of this 7-Eleven)

On the Johor side, I know that there is a [7-Eleven](https://maps.app.goo.gl/sFAknUEc2Yq3XXFU6) at the checkpoint complex that is open 24 hours a day and sells SIM cards, as well as a few mobile shops such as [Digi](https://maps.app.goo.gl/8wnVSYShdk5DuGsU6) in the complex (which, unlike Google Maps claims, close sometimes at or after 10pm).

---

[image]

Comment: Can you not use an eSIM? Physical SIM cards for visitors are becoming harder to find in some places.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks, good idea but I don't know whether I'll have Internet access: [Is there a free wifi accessible at the Woodlands checkpoint in Singapore?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185073/1810)

Comment: In my experience you can buy and set up an eSIM before you actually arrive.

Comment: You can buy the eSIM anywhere in the world, I have one from Airalo that works in almost every country in the world.

Comment: [Why was this question on buying a SIM card at Woodlands checkpoint in Singapore closed?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8608/1810)