# Is there a free wifi accessible at the Woodlands checkpoint in Singapore?

Tags: singapore, wifi

My SIM card purchased in Johor Bahru will likely give me a poor network connectivity once I reach the Woodlands checkpoint. Is there a free wifi accessible at the Woodlands checkpoint in Singapore?